# What happens to outbound notification emails in SP2010 while Exchange server is unavailable/out-of-service?

Tags: sharepoint-server, email, exchange-server

We use an Exchange 2010 server with our SharePoint 2010 deployment, primarily for outbound notifications from SharePoint.  We need to do some maintenance work on the Exchange server, during which it will be out of service for possibly a couple of hours.

We are wondering what SharePoint will do during this period - will the outbound notification emails from SharePoint be queued up and eventually sent once Exchange is operational again, or will those emails be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested in my test farm, where i shut down the exchange server, I noticed immediate alert job runs and no email going as nothing is there.

After 15 min i turn on the exchange server and i noticed all old emails gone. SO no pending alerts waiting for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and trying this out!  So any alerts/notifications generated during those 15 minutes were basically lost - correct?  And did you notice any logs anywhere that may have been generated for each failed notification?

Comment: Yes, they lost. Their is no way to check if alert delivers from exchange or not? Timer job just send the alert to exchange and no record after that....I did not see any thing in logs.